# Joomla Custom Template Mouse Click Not Working

Tags: joomla

I am working on developing a custom theme for a website project on which I am currently working. I have been able to put the zip file together, upload it, and successfully install the template in Joomla. The theme with content shows up beautiful. However, I am not able to click on any buttons in any of the components or modules or even the edit button in the component. In the past, I have created and used a couple themes, and I have never had this issue, so I am not certain as to why I am having this problem now.  I am including my index.php and custom.css files for reference. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated from any Joomla gurus! Thank you much.

index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  Templates.shamrocktours
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2016 Paradimensional Technology. All rights reserved.
 */

// Check if template is being installed in Joomla
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

// Load Bootstrap CSS
JHtml::_('bootstrap.loadCss', true);
 ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Shamrock Tours Web Site">
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo JUri::root(true); ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+French+Canon" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="templates/shamrocktours/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<header role="banner" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <a href="/"><img src="templates/shamrocktours/images/site_logo.png" alt="Shamrock Tours, click for home." id="headerimage"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="usermenu" style="none" />
    </div>
</header>

<nav role="navigation" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="none" />
    </div>
</nav>

<div role="main" id="innerbody">

<div class="row-fluid">
    <aside class="span3">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="side" style="none" />
    </aside>
    <article class="span9">
        <jdoc:include type="message" />
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
    </article>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Main Styles for Shamrock Tours Website */

/* CSS Reset */

a,
article,
aside,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
html,
img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* General Element Styling */

html {
    background: #0D8330;
}

body {
    border: 5px double #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: "IM Fell French Canon";
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1em;

}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.125em;
}


/* Header */

header {
    margin: 25px 25px 0;
}

#headerimage {
    float: left;
    width: 41%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 2;
}

header h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
    position: relative;
    top: -65px;
    left: 397px;
    width: 75% !important;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px #666;
    background: rgba(8,138,43,0.9);
    line-height: 2;
}

/* Content */

#innerbody {
    position: relative;
    top: -99px;
    width: 95%;
    min-height: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 75px 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}

article {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;

}

article h2 {
    margin: 1.05em 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #666;
}

article h3 {
    line-height: 1.2;
}

aside {
    text-align: center;
}

/* Footer */

#footercontainer {
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0.875em;
}
```

Comment: How about removing `z-index: -1` in your css? `#innerbody` . I tested your code and everything worked in general, that was the only minor problem. Maybe an extension is adding some css/js and that's the real source?

Comment: That worked!  Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `z-index: -1` from the `#innerbody`:

```
#innerbody {
  position: relative;
  top: -99px;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 75px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
}
```